# Picture Manipulation with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've been a mobile developer for a few years, and Im looking to expand to cloud integration with my apps. Im looking into AWS solutions to fill this need. I don't know a ton about servers or cloud capabilities, so I'm trying to get pointed in the right direction, and maybe be introduced to some good resources.

My goal is to be able to upload some images to AWS and manipulate these images in the cloud. I'm sure that I'll need S3 to store my images, but is an EC2 instance the correct thing to use to perform the manipulation? This is where my lack of knowledge of servers is holding me back.

I think that the best answer I could get would be a comment on whether my needs from AWS are what I listed above, and a point in the right direction towards articles to tutorials of how to get things up and running.

Thanks much for the help!

Comment: If you can use Lambda instead of EC2 it will probably end up costing you a lot less in the long term. You are on the right track but I definitely suggest looking into Lambda as well.

Comment: What type of "manipulation" do you require? If it is simple resizing, cropping, etc then you could use a service such as [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) or [Imgix](http://imgix.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using AWS Lambda to accomplish what I needed. Running a node.js based lambda function with ffmpeg-like manipulation on the images/media that I was uploading worked out quite well.

Side note :: The processing that I was doing was fairly lightweight, so it worked well with lambda. If things scale up any further I might consider switching the processing to an EC2 instance.